# Dictionary creation inside a function

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Flag':['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], 
'Item':['ball', 'car', 'pen', 'candy'], 
'Char1':[0, 0, 0, 0],
'Char2':[23, 21, 19, 13],
'Char3':[40, 43, 60, 70]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now, let's perform some calculation:

```
df['Char1_avg'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[df.Flag == x.Flag].Char1.mean(), axis=1)
df['Char1_std'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[df.Flag == x.Flag].Char1.std(), axis=1)
df['Char2_avg'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[df.Flag == x.Flag].Char2.mean(), axis=1)
df['Char2_std'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[df.Flag == x.Flag].Char2.std(), axis=1)
df['Char3_avg'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[df.Flag == x.Flag].Char3.mean(), axis=1)
df['Char3_std'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[df.Flag == x.Flag].Char3.std(), axis=1)
```

Finally let's create the following dictionary:

```
Flag_list = ['a','b']

sum_dict = {'Flag':Flag_list,
      'Char1_average':df['Char1_avg'].head(2).tolist(),
      'Char1_std':df['Char1_std'].head(2).tolist(),
      'Char2_average':df['Char2_avg'].head(2).tolist(),
      'Char2_std':df['Char2_std'].head(2).tolist(),
      'Char3_average':df['Char3_avg'].head(2).tolist(),
      'Char3_std':df['Char3_std'].head(2).tolist()}
```

In this way all works fine,
[correct dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Neyho.png)
but I need to define a function that performs the same things, so I have written the following code:

```
def fnctn(dataf):
    param_list=["Char1", "Char2", 'Char3']
    for param in param_list:
        dataf[f'{param}_avg'] = dataf.apply(lambda x: dataf[dataf.Flag == x.Flag][f'{param}'].mean(), axis=1)
        dataf[f'{param}_StDev'] = dataf.apply(lambda x: dataf[dataf.Flag == x.Flag][f'{param}'].std(), axis=1)
        sum_dict = {'Flag':Flag_list,
              f'{param}_average':dref[f'{param}_avg'].head(2).tolist(),
              f'{param}_std':dref[f'{param}_StDev'].head(2).tolist()}
    ref_avg_values = pd.DataFrame(sum_dict)


dataf = df.copy()
fnctn(dataf)
```

But this time the dictionary I get contains only the values of the last iteration:
[wrong dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0daD.png)

How can I get the same dictionary as in the previous case?

Comment: `sum_dict = ...` keeps overwriting `sum_dict` from the previous iteration, leaving only the value from the last iteration available when the loop ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to update it into the dictionary so that you have all the values that are iterated inside the for loop.

Here is the solution to your query:

```
def fnctn(dataf):
    param_list=["Char1", "Char2", 'Char3']
    dictie={}
    for param in param_list:
        dataf[f'{param}_avg'] = dataf.apply(lambda x: dataf[dataf.Flag == x.Flag][f'{param}'].mean(), axis=1)
        dataf[f'{param}_StDev'] = dataf.apply(lambda x: dataf[dataf.Flag == x.Flag][f'{param}'].std(), axis=1)
        sum_dict = {'Flag':Flag_list,
              f'{param}_average':dataf[f'{param}_avg'].head(2).tolist(),
              f'{param}_std':dataf[f'{param}_StDev'].head(2).tolist()}
        dictie.update(sum_dict)
    
    return pd.DataFrame(dictie)

dataf = df.copy()
fnctn(dataf)
```

And the answer is as below:
[image]

Comment: @heartbit did you find the solution useful?

Comment: Yes!! Just tested and it worked, thanks a lot. PS: "I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but my feedback has been recorded." And for my better understanding: why have you added the line df=pd.DataFrame() inside the function?

Comment: Ah! Point. Just an artifact of the trial attempt. Corrected it thanks. Also, if you could find it useful.. please accept it as answer maybe?